# Assign row values from SQL to php variables from URL query

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a SQL table, a php page. Both set up on a website using cPanel hosting.
The SQL table is like this. Table name is "dbase". 
It has two columns, id and name and each column has two rows, say.

```
Id -> 01, 02
Name -> Name1, Name2.
```

What I want to do is.
If my page URL is `examp.le/page.php?id=01` , or something like that which has a parameter 'id' valued as 01.

How do I assign value for php variable in that page say, $name as the corresponding value for 'name' column in the '01' row?

Comment: You need to look at the `$_GET` command. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the parameter form the url using `$_GET[]` and then you have to query from the table to get the `Name`.

Just try this. Hope it helps you.

```
$id = $_GET['id']; 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT name FROM dbase where Id=".$id;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$name;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $name = $row['Name'];
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Now just access `$name` wherever you want